# How can I get non-primary key fields in a GROUP_CONCAT that goes through a linked table?

Tags: mysql, group-concatenation

I have two MySQL tables, `users` and `supervisors`. In this simplified example, `users` has just an ID and a Username, and `supervisors` is a table that links two users together.

I would like to construct a query that returns two columns - a username and a list of their supervisors' usernames.

I have worked out how to do it with just the IDs of the supervisors with this query:

```
SELECT U.username, GROUP_CONCAT(S.supervisorId) AS Supervisors FROM users AS U LEFT JOIN `supervisors` AS S ON S.userId=U.userID WHERE 1 GROUP BY U.userID;
```

Which returns e.g. `1,3` for Steve's supervisors. Instead, I would like it to return `Carol, Dave` (ideally in alphabetical order with a comma after the space, but I can deal with that later if necessary).

Is this possible? I'm not sure how to achive it. Thanks!

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5UVXStcQDixwjPHiWT3ivS/2)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userId` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `users` (`userId`, `username`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Dave'),
  ('2', 'Jane'),
  ('3', 'Carol'),
  ('4', 'Steve');
  
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `supervisors` (
  `supervisorId` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`supervisorId`,`userId`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `supervisors` (`supervisorId`, `userId`) VALUES
  ('1', '2'),
  ('1', '3'),
  ('1', '4'),
  ('3', '4');
```

Comment: Join one more users table joined by `supervisorId` and take name from this table copy for GROUP_CONCAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT u.username, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(su.username) AS supervisors 
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN supervisors AS s ON s.userid = u.userid 
LEFT JOIN users AS su ON s.supervisorid = su.userid 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY u.userid;
```

Comment: huh. For some reason, I thought it wasn't allowed to use non primary keys of a joined table and it was going to need some sort of clever subselect or something to get the usernames!

Comment: @BenHolness Joining condition is **ANY** expression. Even subquery! The only restriction - the output of this expression must be convertable to boolean (in MySQL this means "absolutely any"). Two columns values comparing produces boolean immediately despite of these columns are primary, referenced or something else.

Comment: Oh I meant I thought that when there is a `GROUP BY`, I could only use primary keys for what I am `SELECT`ing, in this case the `GROUP_CONCAT`. Maybe I'm conflating it with when there's a `COUNT`